# As if it /iswas my own

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

Should I say:(ESL perspective)

> "I have to treat English as if it **is** my own''.

Or

> "I have to treat English as if it **was** my own''.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colloquially, both are correct and I hear it all of the time.  However, when expressing something that is hypothetical (i.e. conditional or created for the sake of argument) you should use the subjunctive case:

"I have to treat English as if it *were* my own."